Parse Tree simple example
Consider the grammar G:
S ➝ A | B
A ➝ aB | b | c
B ➝ bA | a | ε

Which of the following strings has two parse trees according to G?
ba
bb
ab
none of the choice
aa

When I draw the parse tree, "ab" seems to be the answer where A parses to a, B and the B here parses to b and A therefore "ab". But the answer reads none of the choice. Where did I go wrong?

(@codeR: Comments are not recommended for …  Answering a question)

Don't edit the body of your question to "delete" it. Instead, try to improve its quality. Check here to get some tips.

You have to terminate with only alphabets/terminals (without any non-terminals/variables). In your case, you end up with abA which is a sentential form, not a sentence. You cannot convert the A to an epsilon and get ab. In fact, ab does not belong to the language given above.

Yeah I think I misunderstood. If I draw a tree for S -> A it can go to a and B then B can parse to b and A, which then A can parse to b. They are all reachable just not in 2 characters, did I understand that correctly?

Be a bit careful with the terminologies. Here some length two strings can be derived, e.g. $S \implies A \implies aB \implies aa $. Similarly, you can derive bb,bc...

There exists no derivation of $G$ that can produce the string $ab$. As codeR's answer pointed out, the resulting string cannot contain nonterminals.
